# What would be a precise interpretation of the addition of an equation to a set of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We can suppose that a set of differential equations is given
[image: DoublePendulum]

which is enough to describe the behavior of a system in particular. Then we suppose that there's additional information for the problem. If we have the double pendulum, now you could imagine that one of the pendulums is attached to a spring so its length varies as $l=l(t)$.

If I add a model to the set of equations: would this still describe the problem? If so, and we propose an educated guess about $l=l(t)$, e.g., $l=k_1 \sin{(\omega_1 t)}$, shouldn't we see this reflected in the solution for the EOMs? (A term similar to $F\propto x^2$, $V\propto x$, for a force or potential, only to illustrate the idea).

Last but not leasat: what would be a precise interpretation of the addition of an equation (not necessarily differential) to a set of differential equations?

Comment: What you propose to replace the rod with is not a spring, but an engine that periodically changes the length of the rod. You are also changing the system from being closed to having interaction from outside. For a simulation of a double pendulum with spring see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231465/how-to-solve-for-the-motion-of-a-double-pendulum, the derivation and use of the system implemented in this function follows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044226/solving-a-system-of-2nd-order-differential-equations-from-sympy.

Comment: Are you speaking about holonomic constraints?